# How do I find the origin of downloaded files?

Tags: samsung, chrome-for-android, file-management, downloading, download-manager

I downloaded a file from Chrome. It shows the download URL in Chrome downloads

[image]

> mv-downloads.s3.eu-west-1.…

However, this is only the domain and I'd like to see the full URL.

Samsung Files shows a different URL:

[image]

> From: app.themetavoice.xyz

Are there logs or some way to see the full URL? Both of these apps give me only the domain :(

Comment: I think it's not possible. If you got root you can `grep -r -l FILENAME /data/data/com.android.chrome`.